# S3 upload on https with dots in bucket name

Tags: amazon-s3, https

I've been trying to implement an ajax upload to Amazon's S3 on a site that uses https, so of course I also have to upload to the secure version of S3, https://bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com.  However, when I try this upload, I end up getting an error that the site has an invalid security certificate.  From what I was reading, this is expected because amazon's s3 certificate only covers one level of subdomains (http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html).  Therefore, I changed the URL I'm uploading to to be https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name, which from what I've also read, is supposed to be equivalent to https://bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com.  However, attempts to upload there gave me a 301 permanent redirect error.  I know for a fact my code works, because when I attempted instead to upload to a bucket with no dots in the name, to https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com, it went through fine, but it also gets a 301 when I attempt https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.

```
 <form id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="..." />
    <input id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit-upload clearfix button blue save"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/', true);
          xhr.send(formData);
     });
</script>
```

So my question is: is there a way to implement an ajax upload to an S3 bucket with dots in the name over https?

Comment: What region is your bucket in?  The way you're doing it is only valid for buckets in US Standard.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot us-west-2

Answer (score 4):

On http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

> Amazon S3 supports virtual hosted-style and path-style access in all regions. The path-style syntax, however, requires that you use the region-specific endpoint when attempting to access a bucket. For example, if you have a bucket called mybucket that resides in the EU, you want to use path-style syntax, and the object is named puppy.jpg, the correct URI is http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/puppy.jpg. You will receive a "PermanentRedirect" error, an HTTP response code 301, and a message indicating what the correct URI is for your resource if you try to access a bucket outside the US East (N. Virginia) region with path-style syntax that uses either of the following:
>
> - http://s3.amazonaws.com
> - An endpoint for a region different from the one where the bucket resides, for example, http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com for a bucket that was created in the US West (Northern California) region